# Ayuda...ListView no muestra Items en fragment hasta despues de entrar a una actividad y regresar

Tags: java, android

Tengo una actividad con 2 fragmentos,

- El primero fragmento que es el primero que se abre, muestra la información correctamente.
- El segundo fragmento tiene un listView que contiene un formato como si fueran comentarios, este listview lo lleno con datos que extraigo de un json de un php, además este fragmento contiene un botón que te manda a una actividad para escribir un comentario y mandarlo.

El problema es que cuando entro a ese segundo fragmento, la lista no se carga, aparece el puro botón de agregar comentario y me di cuenta que si presiono el botón de enviar comentario y regreso al fragmento, ahí es donde se carga la lista. Al parecer, ese fragmento no se ejecuta si no hasta que entro a una actividad y regreso directamente a ese fragmento.

NOTA: los datos del json los recibo con un StringRequest y un ResponseListener. les dejo el código de la clase del fragmento para que chequen a ver  si me falta ponerle algo.

public class NegocioCommentFragment extends Fragment {
    private ListView listView;
    private FloatingActionButton crearComentario;
    private String neg_Nombre;
    final List> mapFill = new ArrayList>();
    private String neg_id;

```
public NegocioCommentFragment() {
    // Required empty public constructor
}


@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // Inflate the layout for this fragment
    return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_negocio_comments, container, false);


}


public void onViewCreated(View view, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);


    crearComentario = (FloatingActionButton) view.findViewById(R.id.agregarComentario);
    listView = (ListView) view.findViewById(R.id.commentsList);

    SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = getActivity().getSharedPreferences("userData", MODE_PRIVATE);
    final String usrapp_id = sharedPreferences.getString("usrapp_id", null);


    //Accedemos a los extras para ectraer nombre e id del negocio
    Intent negocioInfo = getActivity().getIntent();
    final Bundle paqueteInfo = negocioInfo.getExtras();
    neg_Nombre = paqueteInfo.getString("neg_Nombre");
    neg_id = paqueteInfo.getString("neg_id");


    crearComentario.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            Intent enviarComentarioActivity = new Intent(getContext(), EnviarComentario.class);
            enviarComentarioActivity.putExtra("neg_Nombre", neg_Nombre);
            enviarComentarioActivity.putExtra("usrapp_id", usrapp_id);
            enviarComentarioActivity.putExtra("neg_id", neg_id);
            startActivity(enviarComentarioActivity);


        }
    });

    //Creamos arreglos para el adaptador de los comentarios
    String[] negInfo = new String[]{"nombre", "nc_comentario",};
    int[] views = new int[]{R.id.userNameCommentTextView, R.id.userCommentTextView};

    //LLenamos los componentes de la lista de comentarios con los arreglos en donde se guardaron
    SimpleAdapter adapter = new SimpleAdapter(getContext(), mapFill, R.layout.diseno_negocio_comments, negInfo, views);
    listView.setAdapter(adapter);


    //Traemos todos los comentarios del que se han hecho últimamente al negocio
    Response.Listener<String> responseListener = new Response.Listener<String>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(String response) {
            try {
                JSONArray comentariosArray = new JSONArray(response);

                for (int i = 0; i < comentariosArray.length(); i++) {

                    JSONObject comentarioJson = comentariosArray.getJSONObject(i);

                    String nombre = comentarioJson.getString("nombre");
                    String comentario = comentarioJson.getString("nc_comentario");
                    String fechaComentario = comentarioJson.getString("nc_fecha");
                    String calificacion = comentarioJson.getString("calificacion");

                    HashMap<String, String> commentsInfo = new HashMap<String, String>();

                    commentsInfo.put("nombre", nombre);
                    commentsInfo.put("nc_comentario", comentario);
                    commentsInfo.put("fechaComentario", fechaComentario);
                    commentsInfo.put("calificacion", calificacion);
                    mapFill.add(commentsInfo);


                }


            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

        }

    };

    TraeComentariosRequest traeComentariosRequest = new TraeComentariosRequest(neg_id, responseListener);
    RequestQueue queue = Volley.newRequestQueue(getActivity());
    queue.add(traeComentariosRequest);





}

@Override
public void onStart() {
    super.onStart();

}
```

}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Cuando le pasas la variable `mapFill` al adaptador esta está vacía, ya que a esta le asignas valores después de cargar el adaptador. Por eso te muestra los datos después de ir y regresar de la actividad, ya que hay la variable `mapFill` si contiene datos. Ten en cuenta que los datos a la variable `mapFile` se lo asignas después de cargar el adaptador.

```
// Cargas el adaptador al cual le estas pasando la variable mapFill vacia
SimpleAdapter adapter = new SimpleAdapter(getContext(), mapFill, R.layout.diseno_negocio_comments, negInfo, views);
listView.setAdapter(adapter);

// Rellenas la lista que le pasas al adaptador despues de cargarlo
Response.Listener<String> responseListener = new Response.Listener<String>() {
    @Override
    public void onResponse(String response) {
        try {
                ...
                mapFill.add(commentsInfo);
            }
        ...
    }
};
```

#### Solucion

Para solucionar tu problema simplemente carga tu adaptador después de almacenar los datos en la variable `mapFile`, después del response.

```
//Traemos todos los comentarios del que se han hecho últimamente al negocio
Response.Listener<String> responseListener = new Response.Listener<String>() {
    @Override
    public void onResponse(String response) {
        try {
            JSONArray comentariosArray = new JSONArray(response);

            for (int i = 0; i < comentariosArray.length(); i++) {

                JSONObject comentarioJson = comentariosArray.getJSONObject(i);

                String nombre = comentarioJson.getString("nombre");
                String comentario = comentarioJson.getString("nc_comentario");
                String fechaComentario = comentarioJson.getString("nc_fecha");
                String calificacion = comentarioJson.getString("calificacion");

                HashMap<String, String> commentsInfo = new HashMap<String, String>();

                commentsInfo.put("nombre", nombre);
                commentsInfo.put("nc_comentario", comentario);
                commentsInfo.put("fechaComentario", fechaComentario);
                commentsInfo.put("calificacion", calificacion);
                mapFill.add(commentsInfo);


            }

        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
};

//LLenamos los componentes de la lista de comentarios con los arreglos en donde se guardaron
SimpleAdapter adapter = new SimpleAdapter(getContext(), mapFill, R.layout.diseno_negocio_comments, negInfo, views);
listView.setAdapter(adapter);
```

Comment: @Andressualu **Ojo** con el orden de las sentencias, aunque la aplicación se ejecute correctamente, el orden de las sentencias puede cambiar su comportamiento.